# Error in the Date that appear in SMS

Tags: dataextensions, automationstudio, mobileconnect

I have a DE with the field PaymentDueDate, and I used convert in the query to when it fills the field it doesn't show the hour, but only with the day. 
For example, I have the day set to 31 May 0:00 (default convert) in the DE: when I send a message in Mobile Connect the date that appears in the personalized string is the day before the one I set, and the hour appears the hour of the template message creation.

Anyone can help me with this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AMPscript function `DatePart` to get the date that you need (without the time).

For example:

```
%%[ set @month = DatePart(@month,'m')
set @year = DatePart(@year,'y')
set @date = Concat(@month, " ", @year)]%%
```